# Does Akamai include quotas

Tags: cdn, akamai

I'm investigating using Akamai or others CDNs to deliver video.

It's still unclear to me whether in my Akamai account I can limit the number of redirects Akamai will do for me, for example in a given month.

I wish I could limit having Akamai (or any other CDN) handle more than 1 million requests per month.

Of course, beyond quotas queries would be rejected by the CDN, this is what I want.

Besides, since the redirection is distributed amongs the CDNs points of presence, how precise will be the quota ? Can it be precise up to the unit (eg. if quotas is 1,000,000, is it guaranted i'll not get even 1,000,001 requests ?)

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Akamai has no quotas or caps on your service.
What would you like to have happen when your limit is reached?

Your best option may be to use some type of origin auth to gate the type of response served and keep a count at your origin.